# Is IBM Graph still in existence?

Tags: ibm-cloud, janusgraph, ibm-graph

I wanted to use a serverless Graph database similar to non-graph database like IBM's Cloudant, i.e, a remote database easily integrable with the web app. According to the docs, IBM Graph provides free tier 512 MB and 25000 API requests per year, but I've heard it's retired. The docs linked to JanusGraph, which does not have any free tier, similar to Amazon Neptune. So, is IBM Graph still in existence?

(EDIT : On other note, does anyone have any recommendations on any serverless graph database which provides free tier services?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, based on this announcement that IBM Graph was retired.

https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/retirement-of-ibm-graph

Comment: I've already mentioned it in my question. But my question is like many other tools, which remain in existence even after retiring, is it available too?

Comment: It is made very clear in that blog post that : "As of November 27th, 2017, new IBM Graph instances cannot be provisioned. However, existing instances will continue to be supported."

Comment: I got confused by some reviews left in some sites dated 2019. Any advise on the edit part of question, please, since you have worked pretty well in that field?